# Infinite gtk warnings when I right click on the icon

Tags: c, gtk

From this [tuto](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/firstprograms/):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_widget_show(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

I run the executable and right click on the icon,then infinite warnings(the same) reported:

```
GLib-WARNING **: g_main_context_check() called recursively from within a source's check() or prepare() member.

GLib-WARNING **: g_main_context_prepare() called recursively from within a source's check() or prepare() member.

GLib-WARNING **: g_main_context_check() called recursively from within a source's check() or prepare() member.

....
```

Anyone knows how to fix this warning?

**UPDATE**

This problem also exists with `gtk-demo` , is it a gtk bug? Can someone verify that?

Platform: windows XP

**UPDATE2**

I found someone had the same issue:

http://www.dsource.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5179&sid=0368cec966f5a135506cf99b24ec5030

Comment: There could be any number of reasons for this these warnings. I've compiled your code in Linux and no warnings are shown. Try the gtk devel list.

Comment: @James Morris, seems this is a win32 specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in GTK that has been around for quite some time. It is indeed a Windows-only bug. The bug was [reported](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=552041) in September 2008. It's still unresolved, but the good news is that there has been some activity last week (including a proposed patch). So it might get fixed in the next GTK release.